# How can I make this function cleaner?

Tags: python

The start() function is part of a simple ideabank program which can storage ideas. I woud like to make it cleaner, maybe split it for more functions.

You can call ideabank program with second argument ('--list' to list ideas or '--delete' to delete idea) and if you use '--delete' you need to provide a number for third argument (the number of idea which you want to delete). The start function handle these and exceptions.
Do you have any suggestion to make start() function cleaner?

```py
def start():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        ask_for_an_idea()
    elif sys.argv[1] == "--list":
        print_ideas(read_ideas())
    elif sys.argv[1] == "--delete":
        try:
            number = int(sys.argv[2])
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            print("Specify a number after --delete")
        else:
            try:
                delete_idea(read_ideas(), number)
            except IndexError:
                print(f"You have only {len(read_ideas())} idea(s).")
            else:
                print_ideas(read_ideas())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

Comment: Use a proper argument parser like `argparse` or `click`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  arg_parser.add_argument('--list', help='Print ideas')
  arg_parser.add_argument('--delete', default=-1, type=int, help='Specify which idea to delete')
  arg_parser.add_argument('--store_new_idea', help='Prompt for a new idea')

  args = arg_parser.parse_args()
  if args.list is not None:
    print_ideas()
  if args.delete >= 0:
    delete_idea(args.delete)
  if args.store_new_idea is not None:
    prompt_new_idea()
```